# Modsecurity: removeWhitespace not working

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I have the following rule:

```
 SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Client-IP "@ipMatchFromFile test.txt" 
"id:210487,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,t:removeWhitespace,drop,msg:'IP-test'"
```

But When I run it I get the response:

```
T (0) urlDecodeUni: "111.22.33.44 " // note the space before the "
T (0) removeWhitespace: "111.22.33.44"  // perfect! The space has been removed
Transformation completed in 4 usec.
Executing operator "ipMatchFromFile" with param "test.txt" against REQUEST_HEADERS:Client-IP.
Target value: "111.22.33.44"  // target value has no space, hooray!
IPmatchFromFile: Total tree entries: 8, ipv4 8 ipv6 0
IPmatch: bad IPv4 specification "111.22.33.44 ".  // why, oh why, is the space back!
Operator completed in 4 usec.
Operator error: IPmatch: bad IPv4 specification "111.22.33.44 ".  // that space again!
Rule returned -1.
Rule processing failed.
Rule failed, not chained -> mode NEXT_RULE.
```

Please Stack Overflow legends; show me how I can fix it :-)

Comment: Is there a space in the listing in the test.txt file? The transform only happens on the argument in the request that the file entries are compared against - not against the entries in the file.

Comment: There are no spaces in test.txt and Client-IP is the equivalant of X-Forwarded-For.  Something upstream is adding a space, which we need to remove before comparing to test.txt..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, so looks like a bug. Can't say I've honestly tried to match an IP address that required transformation first.

Since it's not really an IP address you could switch to using @pmFromFile rather than @ipMatchFromFile. Note that [the documentation](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#pmFromFile) warns explicitly that you need to use boundaries correctly here:

> Because this operator does not check for boundaries when matching,
>   false positives are possible in some cases. For example, if you want
>   to use @pm for IP address matching, the phrase 1.2.3.4 will
>   potentially match more than one IP address (e.g., it will also match
>   1.2.3.40 or 1.2.3.41). To avoid the false positives, you can use your own boundaries in phrases. For example, use /1.2.3.4/ instead of just
>   1.2.3.4. Then, in your rules, also add the boundaries where appropriate. You will find a complete example in the example:
>
> ```
> # Prepare custom REMOTE_ADDR variable 
> SecAction "phase:1,id:168,nolog,pass,setvar:tx.REMOTE_ADDR=/%{REMOTE_ADDR}/"
>
> # Check if REMOTE_ADDR is blacklisted 
> SecRule TX:REMOTE_ADDR "@pmFromFile blacklist.txt" "phase:1,id:169,deny,msg:'Blacklisted IP address'"
> ```
>
> The file blacklist.txt may contain:
>
> ```
> # ip-blacklist.txt contents:
> # NOTE: All IPs must be prefixed/suffixed with "/" as the rules
> #   will add in this character as a boundary to ensure
> #   the entire IP is matched.
> # SecAction "phase:1,id:170,pass,nolog,setvar:tx.remote_addr='/%{REMOTE_ADDR}/'"
> /1.2.3.4/ 
> /5.6.7.8/
> ```

Comment: Nice approach.Will give that a try tomorrow morning.  Thanks BazzaDP!

Comment: Thanks! That worked, with a small tweak: SecRule TX:REMOTE_ADDR "@pmFromFile blacklist.txt" "phase:1,id:169,t:removeWhitespace,deny,msg:'Blacklisted IP address'"